# Anchor download attribute initiating the download process with a 3 to 5 seconds delay

Tags: html

I am using anchor tag to download a pdf file from same domain and with https. File is getting downloaded successfully.

**Issue:**

When I click on Download, to initiate the download of file it takes around 3 to 5 seconds and then  download starts.

I tried to look for performance of download attribute on anchor tag but could not find anything relevant. Please help in enlighting of my knowledge with supporting documentation on this topic and any personal insites.

Thanks,
A developer

```
 <a target="_self" href="file.pdf" download>Download!</a>
```

Comment: Perhaps you have some internet security installed? Try in a browser opened in incognito mode

Comment: @mplungjan Checked in incognito mode, no changes, still taking same time

Answer (score -1):

If using javascript to solve this helps you by any chance then maybe try this

```js
        document.getElementsByClassName('identified')[0].addEventListener('click', () => {
            document.getElementsByClassName('unidentified')[0].click()
        })
```

```css
        .unidentified {
            display: none;
        }
        .identified {
            cursor:  pointer;
        }
        .identified:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
```

```html
    <a target="_self" class = "identified">Download!</a>

    <a class = "unidentified"target="_self" href="file.pdf" download></a>
```

If this also doesn't work then just try decreasing the load applied by your server or the file size